# Cannot boot Ubuntu from USB 2.0 on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, usb, multi-boot

I'm running OSX 10.7.5 on a Mac Mini 2012. I'm trying to boot Ubuntu, but keep running into issue, after issue. This is what I have done:

Got an extra external hard drive an formatted to MSDOS with disk utility 
 
Mounted The Ubuntu .iso using uNetBootin(will not recognize OSX Extended Journaled partitions)
 
Restarted, held down option to change startup disk, but my external hard drive did not show up
 
Installed rEFIt to see if it would work
 
Restarted, my Ubuntu partition showed up, so I booted from it
 
I got a blackscreen saying "Non-system disk Press any key to continue...", which is unresponsive
 
I've tried remounting the .iso multiple times, no success

Am I doing something wrong? I've never done anything like this, so it is a learning experience. Sorry for any grammar or spelling mistakes, I can only type with one hand, due to a shoulder surgery. Sorry if this is not the correct place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a special ISO created specially for Mac:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.3/release/

Something like ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Linux Mint can boot on Mac without any trouble.

Comment: I will try my luck with Linux Mint and will report back.

Comment: Linux Mint rocks, if you find it worth it don't forget to give a +1 to the answer.